# Global variables in Ocaml

Tags: global-variables, ocaml, caml

I am looking for a way to define global variables in ocaml so that i can change their value inside the program. The global variable that I want to user is:

```
type state = {connected : bool ; currentUser : string};;
let currentstate = {connected = false ; currentUser = ""};;
```

How can I change the value of connected and currentUser and save the new value in the same variable currentstae for the whole program?

Comment: It is not possible to assign to a variable in ML.

Answer (score 5):

Either declare a mutable record type:

```
type state = 
  { mutable connected : bool; mutable currentUser : string };;
```

Or declare a global reference

```
let currentstateref = ref { connected = false; currentUser = "" };;
```

(then access it with `!currentstateref.connected` ...)

Both do different things. Mutable fields can be mutated (e.g. `state.connected <- true;` ... but the record containing them stays the same value). References can be updated (they "points to" some newer value).

You need to take hours to read a lot more your Ocaml book (or its [reference manual](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml-4.01/index.html)). We don't have time to teach most of it to you.

A reference is really like

```
type 'a ref = { mutable contents: 'a };;
```

but with syntactic sugar (i.e. infix functions) for dereferencing (`!`) and updating (`:=`)

Comment: I wouldn't think of `!` and `:=` as syntactic sugar, they're just ordinary functions.

Answer (score 2):

type state = {connected : bool ; currentUser : string};;
let currentstate = {connected = false ; currentUser = ""};;

can be translated to :

```
type state = {connected : bool ref ; currentUser : string ref };;
let currentstate = {connected = ref false ; currentUser = ref ""};;
```

to assign value :

```
(currentstate.connected) := true ;;
- : unit = ()
```

to get value :

```
!(currentstate.connected) ;;
- : bool = true
```

you can also pattern match on its content.

read more about ref [here](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml-4.00/manual003.html)